# (New Firebase Unity SDK) Calling GetValueAsync on a Query wont fire its ContinueWith the first time its called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a highscore in my game using the new Firebase Unity SDK but I've run into some problems while trying to update my highscore-list. This is the code Im running when trying to update my highscore list.

```
public void GetHighscore(Action<DataSnapshot> callback) {
    highscoreRef.OrderByChild("total_score").LimitToLast(10).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
            // Handle the error...
            Debug.Log(task.Exception.Message);
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted) {
            callback(task.Result);
        }
    });
}
```

The first time GetHighscore gets called it will never enter the lambda function inside ContinueWith. However, the second time I call it, it will enter the lambda function and work as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/pkWLt_5piUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebaser here...

Update:  I do see an issue here we will correct in our next Beta release.  If you have complex queries, do not have any indices set up and have no data, there is an error handling the event (you will however eventually get a single event once you get any data).

Until we fix this, you may be able to work around the issue by having at least some data under the target path or adding an index (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).  I'm sure the former works, but haven't verified the latter workaround.

---

I am not seeing what you are seeing.  I would double check that you are handling cases where say the Result might be null or empty in your callback.
Our support folks are good at walking through issues with you.

https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.OrderByChild("total_score").LimitToLast(10)
  .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(x => {
    if (x.Result == null) {
      Debug.Log("null!");
    } else if (!x.Result.HasChildren) {
      Debug.Log("no children!");
    } else {
      foreach (var child in x.Result.Children) {
        Debug.Log(child.ToString());
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I do have a lot of data to fetch. Well "a lot" is around 5000-10000 entries under highscore. I forgot to add the index on rule for total_score until a majority of the entries had already been collected and I'm not sure if rules are retroactive when it comes to indexon? Maybe that's why it's acting wierd.

However, the code you suggested above wouldnt do much in my case since it never even enters the lambda function. So whatever is inside dont matter much.

Comment: I understand if you cant give an exact date or anything but about how long until the next beta release is available for the public? =)

Comment: next beta is on the order of a few weeks and likely the last update before the new year.  Let me see what I can do.  I'll reply back here.

Comment: Ok, thanks a bunch. Oh and I also wanted to let you know that it is indeed working just fine like you said on other less complicated queries/data.

Comment: So I did something similar today but this time I set a child in my database using FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("a child somewhere").SetRawJsonValueAsync("some pretty long string").ContinueWith() and just like in my previous case it never enters ContinueWith. The data is being stored correctly and without errors in my firebase project but it just wont give me a callback which is quite annoying.

Comment: Still same problem with my unity code that use 'Firebase SDK 6.0.0' @Grodslukarn did you solve the issue? Could you share us the last results?