# Unity freezes at firebase GetAsyncValue().ContinueWith()

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have the latest firebase unity SDK - 4.3.0
My Unity version is 2017.2.0f3

In my script, if I have two calls to GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(), the first one is executed normally and the second one halts. If I somehow merge the two calls into one, the program halts at the first call.
I have already set the database URL and reference.

```
IEnumerator fetchData()
{
    int fetchGameDataStatus = 0;
    int fetchPlayerDataStatus = 0;
    try
    {
        reference.Child("PitJumping").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(fetchTask =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Debug.Log("Fetching data");
                    int i = 1;
                    if(fetchTask.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        foreach(var question in fetchTask.Result.Children)
                        {
                            int j = 1;
                            Dictionary<int,string> temp = new Dictionary<int, string>();
                            foreach(var option in question.Children)
                            {
                                temp.Add(j,option.Value.ToString());
                                j++;
                            }
                            gd.dict.Add(i, temp);
                            i++;
                        }
                        Debug.Log("End of task");
                        fetchGameDataStatus = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log(fetchTask.Exception.Message);
                        fetchGameDataStatus = 2;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.Log(e.Message);
                    Debug.Log("In fetch task catch!!!");
                    fetchGameDataStatus = 2;
                }
                Debug.Log("Reached");
            });
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        Debug.Log (e.Message);
        fetchGameDataStatus = 2;
    }
    yield return new WaitUntil(()=> fetchGameDataStatus>0);
    Debug.Log("fetchGameDataStatus = " + fetchGameDataStatus);
    Debug.Log("Going to fetch PlayerData");
    try
    {
        Debug.Log ("Reference set");
        reference.Child("users").Child("sampleUserID").Child("PitJumping").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(fetchTask =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Task for PlayerData started");
                try
                {
                    if (fetchTask.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        pd.questionsCompleted = int.Parse(fetchTask.Result.Value.ToString());
                        fetchPlayerDataStatus = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fetchPlayerDataStatus = 2;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.Log(e.Message);
                    fetchPlayerDataStatus = 2;
                }
            });
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        Debug.Log (e.Message);
        fetchPlayerDataStatus = 2;
    }
    yield return new WaitUntil(() => (fetchGameDataStatus>0 && fetchPlayerDataStatus>0));

    Debug.Log("fetched GD= " + fetchGameDataStatus);
    Debug.Log("fetched PD= " + fetchPlayerDataStatus);
}
```

gd is an object of GameData class
pd is an object of PlayerData class

```
[Serializable]
class GameData
{
    public Dictionary<int,Dictionary<int,string>> dict;
    public GameData()
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class PlayerData
{
    public int questionsCompleted;
    public PlayerData(int x)
    {
        questionsCompleted = x;
    }
    public PlayerData()
    {
        Debug.Log("Empty constructor");
    }
}
```

Sorry for not properly following MCVE, I couldn't exactly pinpoint the cause of the error.
I realise there already is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679118/new-firebase-unity-sdk-calling-getvalueasync-on-a-query-wont-fire-its-continue) on stackoverflow but the answer didn't help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same **problem**. `GetValueAsync()` was performing as expected when the "path" had data in, but it freeze when path pointed to an empty node.

The **cause** was that I had DeltaDNA and Firebase plugin at the proyect and the resolver was breaking some important dependency for Firebase.

The **solution** was to delete both, import Firebase, disable the auto-resolution for the resolver and import DeltaDna without the "dependencies.xml" file (and the folder "deltadna-sdk-unity-notifications" under "Plugins/Android").