# C# .NET 4, How to pass the task completion result to another method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, callback

I am integrating Google Firebase in Unity Game Engine using C#.

Here's my code:

```
FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.SetEditorDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl);
var firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance;

firebaseDatabase.GetReference("SomePath").GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>{
    HandleCallback(task.Result.ToDictionary());
});

void HandleCallback(dictionary<string,object> dic)
{
    Debug.Log(dic.Keys.Count);
}
```

I need to somehow pass the result to another method to handle completion. I can't seem to get this to work.

here's no error, the log is just empty.

However if I call the `Debug.Log(dic.Keys.Count)` inside the Task it works.

Hope to learn and make this work. 
Thank you.

Comment: [Is this relevant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679118/new-firebase-unity-sdk-calling-getvalueasync-on-a-query-wont-fire-its-continue)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for the link, although I tried the solution mentioned there and still can't get the callback method fired.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is strange, but I noticed if I manually create a dictionary from the result instead of using `"ToDictionary()"` the callback method is fired.

Hope it saves you time if you are having the same issue.